# Use SWIG to generate multiple modules

Tags: python, c++, swig

Using SWIG to generate a Python binding for my C++ project has not been easy but I have finally been able to do so. The only issue is that the generated `.py` file that houses essentially the class and method definitions of my wrapped C++ code (but callable for Python) is quite large. I basically want to modularize the generated `.py` file into submodules of relevant classes.

Here is a basic and stripped down sample of what my swig interface file looks like:

```
%module example
%{
/* these two headers should belong to ModuleOne */
#include "header1.hpp"
#include "header2.hpp"

/* these two headers should belong to ModuleTwo */
#include "header3.hpp"
#include "header4.hpp"
}
%include "header1.hpp"
%include "header2.hpp"
%include "header3.hpp"
%include "header4.hpp"
```

And from Python importing the package would be done like so:

```
from example import *
```

I find this messy as I either need to import each class individually with `from example import ClassOne` or import the entirety of the module.

How could I go about creating "submodules" of the swig generated .py file allowing me to modularize my project a bit cleaner and import those without necessarily importing the entire package. For example something like:

```
import example.ModuleOne
import example.ModuleTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add an `__init__.py` file that imports both modules, something like this:

```
from example.ModuleOne import *
from example.ModuleTwo import *
__all__ = [x for x in dir() if x[0] != '_']
```

The last line allows your program to use `from example import *` to import everything.

Edit: I've just read your question a bit more closely and realise you want to import just one of your submodules. You still need an `__init__.py` file to make your two modules into a package, but it can be empty. Your interface files should include a package declaration, e.g. `%module(package="example") ModuleOne`.

Comment: The issue isn't importing the submodules, it's creating them in the first place. When running `swig -c++ -python example.i` there is 1 example.py file created that houses all of the class/method calls. I am trying to separate this file into submodules. Similar to numpy making use of different .so files for the modules such as fft, linalg, etc. with respective .py files housing the definitions

Comment: You need a `.i` file for each submodule. It needs to `%include` the header files relevant to that submodule. Put all the generated files, and `__init__.py`, in one directory to make a package with the same name as the directory.
The SWIG documentation describes this quite well.
https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/Python.html#Python_nn72

Comment: This makes sense. I have been able to successfully build submodules this way using setuptools but my issue now arises with keeping the generated binary in the respective submodule folder. I posted a new question here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75132480/setuptools-build-multiple-extensions