# setuptools build multiple extensions

Tags: python, setuptools, swig, pypi, distutils

I have a c++ project I have successfully swigged for python and PyPI. My issue is when building multiple extensions with setuptools, the generated binaries from swig are not stored in the respective modules directory. Here is an example of what my file structure looks like within my project after running my `setup.py` script.

```
example_project/
├── setup.py
├── _module1.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── _module2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── _module3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
└── pyAPI/
    ├── module1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module1.i
    │   └── module1.py       
    ├── module2/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module2.i
    │   └── module2.py       
    └── module3/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module3.i
        └── module3.py
```

Is there a way to keep generated files in the folder they are relevant to, for example like this:

```
example_project/
├── setup.py
└── pyAPI/
    ├── module1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module1.i
    │   ├── module1.py       
    │   └── _module1.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    ├── module2/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module2.i
    │   ├── module2.py       
    │   └── _module2.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    └── module3/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module3.i
        ├── module3.py       
        └── _module3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

My `setup.py` file contains nothing fancy, I simply declare the extensions source files and swig_opts then call them with `ext_modules=[module1,module2,module3]`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html
you can specify the paths to sub-packages in the naming convention of the extension as a Python dotted name.

So, `Extension(name="...")` per extension in your case should be `name="PyAPI.module1._module1"`, `name="PyAPI.module2._module2"`, etc.